# JSOM : Unable to update Custom list item

Tags: list, jsom, access-denied, updatelistitems

I have Read User having read Permission.

I'm trying to update the list item using JSOM. But I get below error

**"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."**

```
    try {
    var list = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle("ListName");

    var reportListItem = list.getItemById(CommentId);
    reportListItem.set_item('Reported_Flag', '1');
    reportListItem.set_item('Report_Comment', commentText);
    reportListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        $('#reportModal textarea').val("");
        $("#reportModal").modal("hide");



    }, function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ULS.enable = true
        ULSOnError(" - Unable to get report the comment in Comments list - " + textStatus + errorThrown, location.href, 0)
    });
}
catch (error) {
    console.log("  - " + error.message);
    ULS.enable = true;
    ULSOnError(" - " + error.message, location.href, 0);
}
```

Comment: You can't update using `Read` permission. You need to elevate the permission to `Write` on the list at least. Also, if you are going to be doing this on multiple lists, would make sense to give `Full control` on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Using JSOM you have the exact same permissions as the current user (no more and no less), so if the current user only have read permission, then you can't update.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the list items using JSOM with only **Read** permission.

In order to add/update/delete list items, you should at least have **Contribute** permissions.

For more understanding, check below article:

[Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels).